# Paypal IPN cURL not working

Tags: php, ssl, curl, paypal, paypal-ipn

So my paypal php IPN script stopped working. I actually had this problem before and it turned out my hosting provider had to move me to a centOS6 server so I had TSL1.2

But it only worked for a few days.

• I have a SHA-256 SSL certificate, so that's not the problem:
Just had comodo check if my setup was right:

https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1766&viewlocale=en_US&direct=en

My IPN script stops here:

```
error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN 
message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
```

So it must be a `cURL` problem, right?

But my hosting provider keeps telling me it might be coding issue.
Well, I have used this script for years and I'm using it on 6 other servers with no problems. It only stopped working on this one server.

What should I tell my hosting provider? To look into this the `cURL` issue or identify whatever else is wrong on my server? I just know its not my coding, because that's an un-edited IPN file from paypal and it works on 6 other servers.

Comment: Well, when I try to display errors with
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
I don't get any. But the whole script simply stops after the curl request:

error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);

and the IPN-debug says: ....

Comment: INVALID
[2016-02-18 03:05 Australia/Sydney] Invalid IPN: cmd=_notify-validate
[2016-02-18 03:06 Australia/Sydney] HTTP request of validation request:POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1
Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com
Accept: */*
Connection: Close
Content-Length: 20
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: ACTUALLY: I see
SSL connect error

Comment: You are running into the [POODLE problem](https://www.angelleye.com/paypal-ssl-error-poodle-vulnerability/).

Comment: AHA. THAT could bit it!